# Iterate two <Iterable> objects to compare data between them

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, iterable

I am working on with a firebase database and android studio.

I am making a recommendation system. The db has 26 travel destinations each with some attributes. (activities, region, weather, time of the year to go)
Destination number 1 : [ https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrkpP.png ]
Those are values that will never going to change.

On the other hand. i ask people a series of questions and they are being saved on the database. responses to questions 1,2, and 3: [ https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJgMn.png ]

I want to check on the responses if the response has anything in common with the destination features. and if it does, i want to increment an int called score ( i also created an arraylist Destination: is made with the name, the id from the destinations db and also has an int score)

Firebase lets me get an   from a child that has many childs.

```
Iterable<DataSnapshot> destinosHijos = dataSnapshot.child("destinos").getChildren();
Iterable<DataSnapshot> destinosRes = dataSnapshot.child("respuestas").child(codigo).child(user).getChildren();
```

if i want to iterate two lists and compare something between them i would do something like this (hypotecally)

```
for(int i=0;i<destinationsDB.size();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<responsesDB.size();j++){
            String destinationR=destinationsDB.get(i).getRegion();
            String responsesR=responsesDB.get(j).getRegion();
            if(destinationR.equals(responsesR){
                score++;
            }
        }
    }
```

i can't do the same with de foreach. i tried to get all the destination's region and all the responses that had "region" in them. but when i use a foreach inside another is not the same with the forloop

if i try.

```
for (DataSnapshot hijo : destinosHijos) {
// all of the regions from all of the destinations
            String destinoRegion= hijo.child("region").getValue().toString

        }

        for (DataSnapshot res : destinosRes) {
            // all the responses with "region" on them
            if (res.child("region").exists()) {
                if(res.child("region").getValue.equals(destinoRegion)){
                    score++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I modified it becuase the actual one is waay longer.

anyways. when i try to println - res.child("region").getValue.equals(region) - it only prints out 2 false times. that is 2 responses that have "region" on it.

instead of printint 2 * 26 = 72 times, that would be making comparing each response with each destination (that's what the forloop would do).

Thank you in advance if you read all that.

Comment: Not sure about it but `res.child("region").getValue.equals(destinoRegion)` tries to compare whatever the `getValue()` returns to the string `destinoRegion`. Judging from you your code (3 lines above), you do `getValue().toString()` so `getValue()` probably returns something else

Comment: Hi. I suggest you to print destinoRegion and also res.child("region"). Also try to assign res.child("region") to a String instead of comparing directly on the if statement.